# How was mixolidian mode introduced in Northeastern Brazilian Music?

Tags: scales, history

[Northeastern region of Brazil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northeast_Region,_Brazil) has a great variety of traditional and folkloric music genres. The most well-known genre is [forró](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forr%C3%B3), followed also by baião and xaxado.

These music genres are usually characterized by its instrumentation (accordion, zabumba (a snare drum variation), triangle, rebecha and so on). These genres usually portrait as a topic the harshing rural life in the region, [characterized by its dry bioma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caatinga).

Finally, there's also a very unique characteristic in these music genres: **they are played on mixolydian scale**. This characteristic is very particular and remarkable from the music at Northeastern Brazil, and it's not present in the music from the rest of the country.

**How was mixolydian introduced in that particular region and why it's not as present in the rest of the country's folk music?**

---

Quinteto Armorial - Do Romance ao Galope Nordestino (1974) :

Luiz Gonzaga - Asa Branca ft. Fagner, Sivuca, Guadalupe :

Cego Com Cego · José Miguel Wisnik · Tom Zé :

Comment: I can't begin to answer, but I can think out loud:
* Why is a certain feature more prominent in the music culture of one region than in that of its neighbors? Well, for any of the many reasons that cultures and music-cultures retain their distinctive traits. Adherence to genre? cultural value placed on regional identity? I can only speculate.
And...

Comment: ... and: You use the term "introduced," which assumes outside influence. Might it not have developed internally? Mixolydian is certainly a feature in many music cultures (Appalachian, Scottish/Irish, Scandinavian); did they all cross-pollinate, or is there something about Mixolydian that causes it to spontaneously develop in many music-cultures?

Comment: @AndyBonner "Might it not have developed internally?" Thanks for considering this! It's totally possible too.

Comment: Do you know what scales and modes are common in surrounding areas where Mixolydian is not used? Was mixolydian used there prior to the introduction of the accordion? (We know a good deal about its history and the music it was originally designed to play.)

Comment: Would this help you find more specific material about your question?  http://lanic.utexas.edu/project/etext/llilas/ilassa/2008/ferrari.pdf

Comment: Not only mixolydian, but dorian mode as well, having for me (native from northeast from Brazil) the minor equivalent of the mixolydian. I'm not sure, but I'm prone to believe that, because of the probable influences of indigenous music in Xaxado and Xote genres, that were basically the foundation for the Forró, the "mixolydian sound" got more popular on the genre. You can find some brazilian indigenous music where that sound is quite common.

Comment: well, what's characterstic for mixolydian?
the interval between 3rd and 7th is a tritone.
maybe that
to expand, I always percieve music from Brazil as having a "implicit" bitonality... and probably the mixolydian mode lends itself well with the "implicit" tritone